# Wrap text in td set blank space in next td HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created one simple demo here in which I have shown the table with two `td` - one without text wrap, and one with wrap. But as you can see the first one shows perfectly fine, but the second shows space after first text and shown other `td` details after wrapped text how can I show it in one row?

[image]

```css
.customtable tr,
.customtable td,
.customtable tbody,
.customtable th {
  border: 1px double black !important;
  border-bottom: 1px double black !important;
  border-top: 1px double black !important;
  border-right: 1px double black !important;
  border-left: 1px double black !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-responsive customtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5" class="text-center Assessmentmainheader">
        ASSESSMENT

      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="160" class="Assessmentheader text-center">Student Name</th>
      <th class="Assessmentheader text-center">Subjects</th>
      <th class="Assessmentheader text-center">Assessment</th>
      <th class="Assessmentheader text-center">Marks</th>
      <th class="Assessmentheader text-center">View</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="asmnt in AssessmentList" class="ng-scope">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">dasda asd sdasdas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center ">Mathematics</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <span style="color: #fff">Add</span> </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a class="ng-scope">Add Marks</a>
      </td>
      <td class="marksnotview">
        <span>No View</span>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#"><i style="font-size:1.3em" class="fa fa-eye custompointer"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody ng-repeat="asmnt in AssessmentList" style="height:350px; overflow-y:auto" class="ng-scope">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">dasdasd asdas asdaddasdasdasdas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center ng-binding">Social Studies</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <span style="color: #fff">Add</span>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center ng-scope">
        <a>Add Marks</a>
      </td>
      <td class="marksnotview">
        <span>No View</span>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center ng-hide">
        <a href="#"><i style="font-size:1.3em" class="fa fa-eye custompointer"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to show all the wrapped text in one `td` with other `td` details with it.
I tried but not able to solve it. Any fix for this?

Comment: colspan instead of rowspan

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have to use rowspan because it may have more than one rows at next in future so I have to use rowspan instead of colspan.

Comment: so what is the issue :) you explicitly made it 2 rows so it's 2 rows

Comment: unrelated note. `border: 1px double black !important;` is enough, you don't need the other 4 borders

Comment: It's difficult to know exactly what the desired effect is. Can you update the question with a diagram of what you're looking for?

Comment: its unclear what you asking for...

Comment: @Bhuwan what this sir has done I want exactly the solution

Comment: The desired result is for the "Subject" cell to be the full height of the row matching the height of the "Student Name" cell to the left.  
The reason why rowspan="2" and a second <tr></tr> is used is because the table is probably being generated with code.  The code counts the number of child "subject" rows and adds +1 to get the rowspan.  Then it iterates over the child subjects and generates separate <tr></tr> rows for each.  There may even be an inner iteration over assessments per subject.  To do this differently for the first child by having it in the same row as the parent is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `rowspan` is causing issues. It looks like you want to remove the `rowspan`, then remove the extra rows.

```css
.customtable tr,
.customtable td,
.customtable tbody,
.customtable th {
  border: 1px double black !important;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-responsive customtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5" class="text-center Assessmentmainheader">
        ASSESSMENT

      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="160" class="Assessmentheader text-center">Student Name</th>
      <th class="Assessmentheader text-center">Subjects</th>
      <th class="Assessmentheader text-center">Assessment</th>
      <th class="Assessmentheader text-center">Marks</th>
      <th class="Assessmentheader text-center">View</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="asmnt in AssessmentList" class="ng-scope">
    <tr>
      <td>dasda asd sdasdas</td>
      <td class="text-center ">Mathematics</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <span style="color: #fff">Add</span> </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a class="ng-scope">Add Marks</a>
      </td>
      <td class="marksnotview">
        <span>No View</span>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#"><i style="font-size:1.3em" class="fa fa-eye custompointer"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody ng-repeat="asmnt in AssessmentList" style="height:350px; overflow-y:auto" class="ng-scope">
    <tr>
      <td>dasdasd asdas asdaddasdasdasdas</td>
      <td class="text-center ng-binding">Social Studies</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <span style="color: #fff">Add</span>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center ng-scope">
        <a>Add Marks</a>
      </td>
      <td class="marksnotview">
        <span>No View</span>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center ng-hide">
        <a href="#"><i style="font-size:1.3em" class="fa fa-eye custompointer"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when it dynamically set at that time not working while here it is working strange.

Comment: @3rules you’ll need to explain in greater detail what you’re looking for